# Is high frequency alternating current capable of rotating induction motor?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits

I have 100khz AC power that can light up a bulb, can I use this to run small induction motor? I want the Lorentz force to push rotor coil, I know that motor would not rotate at 100000hz rate but it does not need to be that fast, all I want is some sort of mechanical frequency changer using induction motor technology, adding some capacitors to motor would help to achieve rotation?

Comment: electric-circuits.